# Search and replace of several sentences using bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, if-statement, delimiter

now, i have script to search and replace words. How can i do the same for sentences or wordcombinations.
Look on my script:

```
first_words="wwe wwf ziggler"
second_words="tna njpw okada"

mywords=( $first_words )
mywords2=( $second_words )

if [ ${#mywords[@]} != ${#mywords2[@]} ];then
        echo "you should use the same count of words"
        exit 1
else
        echo "you are using the same count of words, continue ..."
fi

for ((i=0;i<"${#mywords[@]}";++i)); do
        sed -i "s/${mywords[$i]}/${mywords2[$i]}/g" text.txt
done
```

It works, but only replace word by word. But if i want to replace several wordcombinations on several wordcombinations. 
For example "dolph ziggler, john cena, randy orton" i want to replace on "cm punk, hulk hogan, rey mysterio". What i should do in this situnation. May be i should handle some delimiter. In first case, the space was delimiter for words, but in this situation, i can't use space. What i can do ? Please help.

Comment: Why are you assigning to variables and then using them in the array instead of just assigning directly to the array?

Comment: because it is not all script. it is a part of script. i should use input parameters in variables.

Comment: How are you determining where elements start and end?

Comment: in all document

Comment: to go in the same direction as @123 how arguments will be split into sentences, in your example words are split by space (or tabs) because this is the default

Comment: i think maybe comma, should be delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysentences=( "first sentence" "second sentence" )
mysentences2=( "new first" "new second" )
...
for ((i=0;i<"${#mysentences[@]}";++i)); do
    sed -i "s/${mysentences[$i]}/${mysentences2[$i]}/g" text.txt
done
```

Warning, if sentences can contain `/` they must be escaped and if they can contain character which have a special meaning in regex can be escaped in perl with `\Q` and `\E`.

```
perl -i -pe 's/\Q'"${mysentences[$i]//\//\\/}"'\E/'"${mysentences2[$i]//\//\\/}/g" text.txt
```

Note: it's not safe, injection still possible

```
mysentences=( "bar" )
mysentences2=( '@{[`echo ok >&2`]}' )

perl -pe 's/\Q'"${mysentences[$i]//\//\\/}"'\E/'"${mysentences2[$i]//\//\\/}/g" <<<"foo bar baz"
```

passing sentences as arguments to prevent injection

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$oldtext=shift;$newtext=shift}s/\Q$oldtext\E/$newtext/g' "${mysentences[$i]//\//\\/}" "${mysentences2[$i]//\//\\/}" <<<"foo bar baz"
```

Comment: You can pass as env vars before calling perl to prevent injection, `var1="${mysentences[$i]//\//\\/}" var2="${mysentences2[$i]//\//\\/}" perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{"var1"}\E/$ENV{"var2"}/g' <<<"foo bar baz"`

Comment: @123 yes, also can be passed as first two arguments

Comment: They aren't arguments, they are env variables set for the process that is run after.

Comment: Ahh right, misunderstood, thought you were talking about my suggestion.